# Database connection re-established on FCM notification on android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my Flutter/Firebase App I am using the Firebase Database feature `.info/connected` to indicate whether a device is online or not. So when a user opens the app, an entry it will be added to the list of active devices in `.info/connected` and vice versa. Then a cloud function is triggered which updates the user's Firestore `isOnline` record correspondingly.

Additionally I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to the users.

Here comes the problem: If a FCM notification is sent to an android device, where the app is currently in background and not connected to `.info/connected`, this connection gets re-established and the user is set to `online` even if the app was not opened.

This produces a false indication of the user status.
Can I turn off this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like receiving the FCM message reactivates the application code, which then reconnects to the database and (correctly) sets the `.info/connected`.

If you don't want to use this as a signal that the user is online (although clearly their app is online), you have a few options:

- Pick a different action to signal that the user is active. For example use the app/screen lifecycle of your app, since you indicate that you want the opening of the app to be the event that signals the user being online.

  If you've already wired up `onDisconnect`, you might want to continue
  to use *that* for marking the user as offline in case of dirty
  disconnnects (like when the app crashes).
- Explicitly manage the connection to the Firebase backend, by [calling `goOffline` and `goOnline`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase-class.html) in response to app/screen lifecycle events.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. In contrast, on iOS it does not reconnect when a notification message is delivered. So iOS is working very well. This must be android specific. Can the `reactivation of the application code` be disabled somehow?

Comment: There's no flag or anything like that. It really depends on how you're receiving the FCM messages and (assuming that is only in a background service) what else you do in that service. I've never investigated though, as in most of my cases: what you're seeing would be the ideal situation as it means I can communicate with the database again once the app received an FCM message. That is in fact a (unfortunately not common enough) use-case: sending a so-called tickle message through FCM to wake up the database connection again, so it can get fresh data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Meanwhile I figured out the difference between Android and iOS. As you know I am listening to `_firebaseDatabase.ref().child('.info/connected').onValue` and depending on the emitted value I set the users status. On iOS the listener doesn't fire when the app is in background and a fcm msg arrives. This is either due to the listener stops listening when in background or the fcm msg simply doesn't wake up the device. So I think I need to rebuild that whole user presence thing.